# pandas standard deviation with bell curve graph using stats norm

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My data frame is

[image]
Here i want standard devistion for the above dataframe and need a standard deviation graph.

I used below code

```
import numpy as np   
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab as pl 
import pandas as pd


h=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\monthlyReports\standard_deviation\stan_rawdata.xlsx")

fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))  
pl.plot(h,fit,'-o')
pl.hist(h,normed=True)     
pl.show()
```

but I am getting type error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-830c3a5f6c7c> in <module>()
      7 
      8 
----> 9 fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))  #this is a fitting indeed
     10 
     11 pl.plot(h,fit,'-o')

      ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in pdf(self, x, *args, **kwds)

  1650         args = tuple(map(asarray, args))

   1651         dtyp = np.find_common_type([x.dtype, np.float64], [])

-> 1652         x = np.asarray((x - loc)/scale, dtype=dtyp)

   1653         cond0 = self._argcheck(*args) & (scale > 0)

   1654         cond1 = self._support_mask(x) & (scale > 0)


TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: post full traceback of your error

Comment: Update this full traceback error in your question and provide dataframe in form of code not as image, so that it is easy to generate the same error in our machines.
Based on error, you should take mean of specific column not for whole dataframe.

Comment: you are getting error because you are passing whole dataframe in `np.mean(h)` which accepts only numeric.